# Hard disk drivers are not clickable in windows explorer's right pane

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

in windows explorer, when 'Computer' is selected on left panel, on right panel, hard disk drivers are not clickable, but hard disk drivers on left panel is clickable.

for the hard disk drivers on the right pane, they can be opened by context menu, but not left click.

why?

Comment: You mean 'drives'.. i.e. 'partitions' rather than drivers, which would not be visible from Explorer?

Comment: the drives I meant was like C drive, D drive.

Answer (score 0):

it turned out that the default command in context was 'cmd' instead of 'open'. changed the defualt command to 'open' in context, the issue was gone.

the command used:
reg add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell /ve /d "none" /f